# PInvokeStackImbalance was detected

Tags: dll

When I use c++ dll in c#,  I get the PInvokeStackImbalance error.
Managed Debugging Assistant 'PInvokeStackImbalance' has detected a problem in.....

Here is the c# code I used:

[DllImport("Mydll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]

public static extern bool MyFunction(char[] logPath, float f1, float f2);

---

c++ dll function
EXTERNC MYDLL_API bool WINAPI MyFunction(char[] logPath, float f1, float f2);

c++ environment : VS 2013 (win32)

c# environment : VS 2013 (.net framework 4.5)

I've been searching for this problem, but couldn't find the answer I'm looking for.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You'll have to lookup what MYDLL_API means.  Good odds that it means __stdcall given the diagnostic.

Comment: thanks. I modified CallingConvention.Cdecl to CallingConvention.Stdcall.